# Can't send a message with the new websocket protocol

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I am trying to develop a websocket server in php.

Here is what I have done so far :
(server part)

```
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($server, "localhost", 10000);
socket_listen($server);

$client = socket_accept($server);

$message = socket_read($client, 5000);

$matches = array();

preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $message, $matches);

$new_key = new_key($matches[1]);

$new_message = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$new_message .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$new_message .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$new_message .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $new_key . "\r\n\r\n";

socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));

$new_message = "Test message !";

socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));

function new_key($key)
{
    $key .= "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    $key = sha1($key);
    $new_key = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i+=2)
    {
        $new_key .= chr(intval($key[$i] . $key[$i+1], 16));
    }

    $new_key = base64_encode($new_key);

    return $new_key;
}

/* End of file server.php */
```

(client part)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:10000');

    ws.onopen = function() {
        alert('Connection open !');

        setInterval(function() {
            ws.send('lol');
        }, 1000);
    }

    ws.onclose = function() {
        alert('WebSocket close !');
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
        alert(e.data);
    }

    ws.onerror = function(e) {
        alert('Error');
    }
};
```

The first `socket_write` works perfectly (for the handshake) and the `open` event is triggered correctly. But the second socket_write doesn't work. I tried to do a `ws.send` on the `open` event with a second `socket_read` in server part, it doesn't work neither.

Thank you if you have an idea !

Comment: You could check out mine, it works fine: http://code.google.com/p/web-socks/  Feel free to use it or hack code out of it!

Comment: On a side note, what browser are you using that accepts the new handshake version?

Comment: I'm using nightly builds of Firefox which use hybi-07 version of websockets.

Comment: I don't know if you still need an answer but you need to implement the new framing format as well - you cannot just send a plain string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I read the doc carrefully and found out how to do it correctly !

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 meaning a sync problem. Try this in your client:

```
var test = function(){
    var myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:10000');
    myWebSocket.onopen = function(e){
        alert('connection open');
        this.send('test1');
        this.send('test2');
    }
    myWebSocket.onmessage = function(e){ alert('message ' + e.data) };
    myWebSocket.onclose = function(e){ alert('connection closed'); this.close(); };
    myWebSocket.send('test3');
};
```

test3 will fail because it is an asynchronous websocket.

Comment: You only replaced `myWebSocket` by `this` ? I tried your code and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you get a second ws.onmessage alert ?

Comment: Ok, sorry thought you received at least 1 onmessage on your example. Guess it has to be a draft 76 handshake issue then.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After checking out this project over here  https://github.com/srchea/PHP-Push-WebSocket I noticed a function called "encode" in this file https://github.com/srchea/PHP-Push-WebSocket/blob/master/lib/Server.class.php before sending the message.

So try to change this

```
socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));
$new_message = "Test message !";
socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));
```

to this

```
socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));
$new_message = "Test message !";
socket_write($client, chr(129) . chr(strlen($new_message)) ."". $new_message);
```